# Spring data cassandra - No keyspace has been specified

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

I'm having a problem with spring data cassandra. Even if a specify the keyspace into CassandraConfig, it is throwing me this error.

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: No keyspace
>   has been specified. USE a keyspace, or explicitly specify
>   keyspace.tablename    at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:147)
>   ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.4.0.jar:na]
>
> CQL [SELECT * FROM test WHERE token='asdasdasdasd';]; No
>   keyspace has been specified. USE a keyspace, or explicitly specify
>   keyspace.tablename;

CassandraConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "com.test.model")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "testKeySpace";
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster =
                new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints("127.0.0.1");
        cluster.setPort(9142);
        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping()
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a link to a Github repo/code that is able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @mp911de I managed to find out the problem. Even if a specified the keyspace in CassandraConfig class, he expected the proprieties from application.properties. I think it's a bug. I created the application.properties and I specified there the keyspace and it worked.

Comment: Would have been nice to see how, and have OP post solution... :-(

Answer (score -2):

Your problem looks a lot like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565204/cassandra-repository-is-always-using-keyspace-from-application-properties-file-n/51674237#51674237).

With `getKeyspaceName()` you tell cassandra which keyspace to use but you also need to create this keyspace:

```
@Override
protected List<CreateKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceCreations() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            CreateKeyspaceSpecification.createKeyspace()
                    .name("your_keyspace_name")
                    .ifNotExists()
    );
}
```