# Cassandra Repository is always using keyspace from application.properties file not from the extended class of AbstractCassandraConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-cassandra, spring-repositories

**I have my data are on different keyspaces, i have more than one keyspace in a spring boot application, so i want my cassandra repositories to be configurable with different keyspaces each rather than having one keyspace in application level. In a spring project, i am looking something like a keyspace should be configurable at Repository level.**

Cassandra Repository is always using **keyspace** from application.properties file, Not working if i extend **AbstractCassandraConfiguration** class and configure keyspace and port.
I have created a Entity, CassandraConfig and Repository and tried to query and update Entity using Respository. Refer my code below.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Entity code:-

```
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKey;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table;

@Table
public class Company {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String companyid;
    private String companyName;
    private String address;
    public String getCompanyid() {
        return companyid;
    }
    public void setCompanyid(String companyid) {
        this.companyid = companyid;
    }
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }
    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

Cassandra config code :-

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractCassandraConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableCassandraRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackageClasses=CompanyRepository.class)
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    public String getContactPoints() {
        return "127.0.0.1";
      }
    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "CompanyDetails";
    }

}
```

Repository code :-

```
import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository;
    import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.Query;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository

    public interface CompanyRepository extends CassandraRepository<Company, String> {
                    @Query(allowFiltering=true)
                    public Company findByCompanyName(String companyname);

                    public List<Company> findAll();
    }
```

***I tried to set keyspace for Repository using the class which extend AbstractCassandraConfiguration instead of application.properties. it didn't work***
cassandraTemplate is working fine. i am getting issue with only Repository.
even if i create and configure CassandraClusterFactoryBean, CassandraMappingContext, CassandraConverter and CassandraSessionFactoryBean beans repository is throwing below exception

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: No keyspace has been specified. USE a keyspace, or explicitly specify keyspace.tablename
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:147) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:179) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.4.0.jar:na]
```

if i add below entries to application.properties file then it is working fine.

```
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=CompanyDetails
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=127.0.0.1
```

**is it possible to set keyspace for Repository through class which extend AbstractCassandraConfiguration class instead of application.properties?**

Feel free to point, if i missed or did something wrong.

Comment: Why did you add `CassandraConfig`? Spring Boot does already everything from your custom configuration above.

Comment: I have my data are on different keyspaces, so i want my cassandra repositories to be configurable with different keyspaces rather than having one keyspace from application.properties file. In a spring project i want my repositories to be configurable with different keyspaces.

Comment: Spring Boot requires a keyspace name to provide a `UserTypeResolver` and the Cassandra `Session`. I think excluding `CassandraDataAutoConfiguration` and setting up a fair bit of own infrastructure is the way to go. Also, check out https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/cql/session/lookup/AbstractRoutingSessionFactory.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to create the keysace. With `getKeySpaceName()` you tell cassandra which keyspace you want to use but if it is not there you'll get an error. To create a keyspace use the following method:

```
@Override
protected List<CreateKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceCreations() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            CreateKeyspaceSpecification.createKeyspace()
                    .name("your_keyspace_name")
                    .ifNotExists()
    );
}
```